# Import model trained in Google Cloud to Android device

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-ml

I have trained a tensorflow model in Google Cloud using instructions from [this link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/flowers-tutorial) and have generated a Binary (application/octet-stream) file having .pb extension. However instead of deploying the model in the cloud, I want to use the model locally in my android device. How can I do the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that and the easiest way of doing it right now is following this code lab: [Tensorflow for Poets 2: TFLite](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

In the code lab you'll have to embed the model as an asset but an evolution you can make is download the model from the Cloud Storage whenever there's a new version of it.

If your model uses operations that are not yet supported by TFLite, you can use [Tensorflow Mobile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android). It probably won't be as fast but it still works fine (There's also a [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0) to understand it better).